# Jenkins doesn't see JAVA_HOME

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I got Maven AQA android project that i'd like to use with Jenkins. I created build, ran it, saw the connection with my repository in logs but evetually it fails with the next error:

[**ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7lFf.png)

I already set JAVA_HOME in [Jenkins environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbI2C.png)
Local environment variables has been set also: [JavaHomeScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0K9a.png)  [PathScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqwIC.png)
The Path to the JDK itself are [correct too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur3ff.png)

I checked all the paths but it's still doesn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Which OS environment the jenkins server/node is running on?
if the node is linux, obviously need to install jdk on that node and set JAVA_HOME to the correct location.

Anyway, Have you tried to println the current content of env.JAVA_HOME?
it might be better to set env.JAVA_HOME in the Jenkinsfile.
just make sure you add double backslashes when you do it thru Jenkinsfile: (windows node):

```
env.JAVA_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_341"
```